# How to solve Javascript console error browserLink:37 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input#checkbox{$index}?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to assign unique `IDs` to an `input` tag in html and I am using `AngularJS` so basically I am using `ng-repeat` to generate the `input` tags but its giving me `error` in `console`

```
browserLink:37 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input#checkbox{$index}
```

Here is my code

```
<div class="chip" data-ng-repeat="item in DeletedKeyphrases track by $index">
    <label></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox{{$index}}" data-ng-model="item.restorekeyselected" data-ng-click="storecheckedkeyphrase(item)"/><label for="checkbox{{$index}}" style="margin-right: 10px;"><span>&#x2714;</span></label>
```

What should I do?